# How to write data to existing excel file using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I want to request some data from a python module tushare.
By using this code, I can each time get a line of data.
However I want to send the server a request for like every 5 seconds
and put all the data within 4 hrs into one excel file.
I notice that pandas is already built in tushare.
How to put the data together and generate only one excel file?

```
    import tushare as ts
    df=ts.get_realtime_quotes('000875')

    df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\stockfile\000875.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with for example

```
df = df.append(ts.get_realtime_quotes('000875'))
```

Given the number of calls, it nay be better to create a data frame and fill it with data rows as they arrive. Something like this:

```
# Here, just getting column names:
columns = ts.get_realtime_quotes('000875').columns
# Choose the right number of calls, N,
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(N), columns = columns)
for i in range(N):
    df.iloc[0] = ts.get_realtime_quotes('000875').iloc[0]
    sleep(5)
```

Another way to do it (possibly simpler and without preallocating the empty data frame) would be storing answers from `tushare` in a list and then applying `pd.concat`.

```
list_of_dfs = []
for _ in range(N):
    list_of_dfs.append(ts.get_realtime_quotes('000875'))
    sleep(5)
full_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```

This way you don't need to know the number of requests in advance (for example, if you decide to write the `for` loop without explicit number of repetitions).

Comment: thank you for your reply. I might ask a stupid question..what do you mean by number of calls??

Comment: it returns one row of data each time, and this row contains 34 columns

Comment: @Qing If you're going to be sending requests every 5 seconds for 4 hours, then it will be N = 4*60*60/5 requests (or calls). So the code first preallocates the data frame of that size and then fills the rows.

Comment: @Qing I added another solution.

Comment: thank you so much! it works for me. btw do you know a way to open the excel file and write without overlapping previous results?

Comment: I think the second solution is more achievable for me. easily understanding!

Comment: Glad I could help. As for appending to an excel file, a safe solution is to read the content to a data frame first, append to it the other data frame, and finally save it back to file. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20221655/5717589) you can append data to separate sheets.