# through a list have the dataframe print to excel a different document. If not into the same document different sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How to get separate excel file of the data frame from a list?

I don't want to make 4 separate functions for each `costcenter`.

```py
import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel(r'c:\temp\code.xlsx') 
    costcenter = ['1130', '1236', '3427', '3148' ]
    for each_costcenter in costcenter:
        y = df[df['COST CENTER']== each_costcenter] 
        y.to_excel(r'c:\temp\code\finalput.xlsx', sheet_name=each_costcenter)
```

I thought I can get `finalput` with 4 sheets of the data but I end up with one sheet with the last from the list.

I wouldn't mind getting 4 separate files with cost center names.

Comment: You're overwriting the Excel file on each invocation. To make different sheets in the same file, check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Loop to Create Excel Sheets with Dataframe Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215508/using-loop-to-create-excel-sheets-with-dataframe-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the Excel writer object first:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'c:\temp\code\finalput.xlsx')
```

Then in your loop:

```
y.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name=each_costcenter)
```

Then after the loop save the file:

```
writer.save()
```

Comment: OMG it works!!!   i tried this before but i couldnt figure it out...i forgot to put writer.save() outside of the loop

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it fixed the problem.