# Insert a panda's dataframe into existant excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel database from which I extract some information. I read it and I store it into a pandas dataframe. With this information I make some calculations and I have to put the results into the same Excel's worksheet.

I know how to convert a dataframe to Excel, but, how can I insert a dataframe into an existant workbook (only the values, without changing the format)?

For example :

This is my panda's dataframe after have done the calculations :

```
Bill Number |  1  |  Ratio  |  0.57  |  Waiter  |  0.3652
```

And this is my Excel's worksheet before edit it :

```
Bill Number |     |  Ratio  |        |  Waiter  |
```

I would like to make a fusion of the dataframe with the excel without modify the format. The result will be this :

```
Bill Number |  1  |  Ratio  |  0.57  |  Waiter  |  0.3652
```

EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Does anyone knows how can I insert the dataframe into a desired location (for example I want that my dataframe starts from cell "C15") ?

Comment: If not a duplicate it's strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20219254/42346

Comment: How can I do If I want to insert the whole into a desired positon (one column to the left and starting in the third row for example) ?