# Add a title to a pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this code to read an excel file:

```
import pandas as pd

DataFrame = pd.read_excel("File.xlsx", sheetname=0)
DataFrame.groupby(["X", "Y"]).size()

res = DataFrame.groupby(["X", "Y"]).size()
print res
```

This code:

```
res = DataFrame.groupby(["X", "Y"]).size()
```

Return how many time the items from X appears in the file for example, if I have the following example:

```
X     Y 
abc   test
abc   test
a     test
```

I get

```
X    Y
abc test  2
a   test  1
```

How can I add a title to the 3rd column, so i can sort it, for example I want:

```
X    Y    Z
abc test  2
a   test  1
```

and how can I write it to an excel file where each column from the output would be a column in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either:

```
res.rename('Z').sort_values().to_excel(...)
```

Or:

```
res.rename('Z').to_frame().sort_values(by='Z').to_excel(...)
```

Comment: OK, it works but it skips a step. The problem is that I want to sort the Z and then write it to xls.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part, please see my edit. You don't need the series to be named to sort the values, so you could swap `rename` and `sort_values`...

Comment: Is it also possible to append it to an existing Excel file?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas)?