# Add rows without overwrite (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

Colleagues, I have the following excel file. But, when I compile the program again, my data is overwritten. I'd like to put each results of the next compilations in a row. I've seen some examples with append, but I can not make it work. Could someone help me, please? !!

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Function':[Output],'Circuit':[gates],'Cost':[cost]},)

df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

Comment: Append to other columns or worksheets? E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas

Comment: @albert append to other rows.

Comment: Probably not the most efficient, but you can read the excel file into a df, append new data into the df, and write the df into a new excel.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there is no direct way to append rows to existing excel

Try this code, it may help

read your excel as dataframe

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx')
```

and your defined dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Function':[Output],'Circuit':[gates],'Cost':[cost]})
```

then write both dataframe to excel

```
df1.to_excel(writer,startrow=0,index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer,startrow=len(df1)+1,header=False,index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It's working!!!  It's a little messy the columns, but no overwriting the data...

Comment: if my answer helped you, would you please accept this answer!

Comment: How I do that?  I'm new here!