# writing the count of items from dataframe to a cell in an excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(v.items()),columns=["Associate","Dailycount"])
```

where `v=r.value_counts()` -v is the count of each associate

`r=pd.Series(Associates)` -r is the series of names of associates

Output of df is-

```
Associate | Dailycount
----------------------
Associate1 | 14
Associate2 | 5
Associate3 | 31
Associate4 | 4
```

Now, I want to write the count of each Associate to an excel sheet which is in a format as-

```
| Date____ | Associate1 | Associate2 | Associate3 | Associate4
-----------------------------------------------
9/19/2017  | 3_________ | 20________ | 16________ | 4__________|
9/20/2017  |___________ | _____________ | ____________ | ____________|
```

Columns of the excel sheet are- Date, associate1, associate2 and so on

I want to write the count of each associate in the cell which is at a particular date(say 9/20/2017)
How can I write it into the excel?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: A sample data would be lot better.

Comment: @user8635794 please add this in your question with a bit of formatting.

Comment: And what did you try to do this? What part is not working?

Comment: @Bharathshetty added it

Comment: @JanZeiseweis I want to write the count of each associate in the cell which is at a particular date(say 9/20/2017) How can I write it into the excel?

Comment: You can read the existing excel file into a dataframe, add your new data and then overwrite the existing file:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas

Comment: @JanZeiseweis could you write me the code for adding data and overwriting the file