# How to add sheet to existing excel file with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook


book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,4,5,6,4,7,8,9],
                   'b':[3,5,6,2,4,6,7,8,7,8,9]})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tab_name', index = False)

writer.save()
```

I get an error
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'

Comment: AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet' that is what I get

Comment: What versions of `pandas` and `openpyxl` are you using? I can't reproduce your error with `pandas 0.18.1` and `openpyxl 2.2.5`

Comment: @DeepSpace Well, we're on 0.22 now. Not sure about `openpyxl` though (psh, who even uses that?!).

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas) for more ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fn = 'test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(fn, header=None)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,4,5,6,4,7,8,9],
                   'b':[3,5,6,2,4,6,7,8,7,8,9]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn, engine='openpyxl')
book = load_workbook(fn)
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tab_name', header=None, index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tab_name', header=None, index=False,
             startcol=7,startrow=6)

writer.save()
```