# Write DataFrame in .xlsx without overwrite the file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I didn't find any solution in other posts. I need to write datframes in an existing sheet of a xlsx file, but of course it overwrites the whole file. How to do it?

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='test2',startcol=10,startrow=20)
writer.save()
```

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it overwrites the file.

Comment: did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47740262/5741205)?

Comment: Ok, this works! Thanks