# File corruption while writing using Pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading data from a perfectly valid `xlsx` file and processing it using Pandas in Python 3.5. At the end I am writing the final dataframe to an Excel file using :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'Data.xlsx'), 
engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_urls': False})
manual_labelling_data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet_A', index=False)
writer.save()
```

While trying to open the `Data.xlsx`, I am getting the error : **We found a problem with some content in 'Data.xlsx'**... On proceeding the file loads into Excel with info : **Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part**

I cannot find out what the problem is.

Comment: What happens when you try opening the Excel file with Pandas? What happens if you write the file to CSV, then try opening the CSV?

Comment: Writing to CSV does not have the issue. Reading the written `xlsx` file using Pandas does not have any issue either.

Comment: Are you actually writing formulas from the dataframe? If so then you should try to isolate the formula that is creating the issue. If not, and the formulas are getting interpreted unintentionally, then you can avoid this by setting the `strings_to_formulas` constructor option to `False`.

Comment: @jmcnamara, that helped. Thanks a ton. Also, could you please provide the link that contains the list of all the available options.

Comment: @Aroonalok The available options are listed under the [XlsxWriter constructor](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor) documentation.

Comment: I had the same problem. I was calling `writer.save()` and `writer.close()` both. Removing `writer.close()` solved the problem!

Comment: Similar to @HarshitJindal, I was using pd.ExcelWriter in a `with` block statement and also calling `writer.save()` at the end of the block. Removing `writer.save()` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @jmcnamara for the help in comment. The issue was that some strings in the data were wrongly being interpreted as formulas. The corrected code is :

```
options = {}
options['strings_to_formulas'] = False
options['strings_to_urls'] = False
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'Data.xlsx'),engine='xlsxwriter',options=options)
manual_labelling_data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet_A', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Very handy I have a column with base64 encoded string and one row starts with `=`, disabling `string_to_formulas` saved my day! Thank you for sharing.