# how do insert data into an existing sheet of Excel?

Tags: python-3.x, excel

Sorry for this question. I am here for the first time.
I have a problem with inserting the data frame into the existing sheet of Excel.

Please, could you show examples of how to do this?

Thank you for helping.

UPDATED:

I forgot to say I've already tried solutions with pd.to_excel - this solution deleted my other sheets in the workbook. And I've tried the solution with openpyxl.load_workbook - load_workbook doesn't work when I have formatting or colors or pivots into my workbook. Even if I have a clean workbook this solution is deleting my previous sheets.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186519/appending-pandas-dataframe-to-existing-excel-document

Answer (score 0):

These questions might help.

[Appending Pandas DataFrame to existing Excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186519/appending-pandas-dataframe-to-existing-excel-document)

[How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas)

[How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for helping. But those articles I've already read and they haven't help me. For example, when I used this way:

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(wk_path + save_file) #engines openpyxl or xlsxwriter no matter

counts_os.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', 
    startcol=1, startrow=1)

writer.save()
writer.close()

I got a new sheet 'test' with deleting all of the previous sheets in my file.

Comment: or, when I tried to use this way: 
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Masterfile.xlsx')

I got an error: Value must be a sequence
@JLT

Comment: The last way works the same as the first (with deleting other sheets). And the last way works when I only have a clear book without pivot tables and so on.

Comment: @trofim_from_russia, you might want to use something different then panda's. I'm using OpenPyxl