# How do I edit XLSX spreadsheets with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I edit spreadsheets using pandas, or any other library.

I have a CSV where I do the data reading and some filters, which I intend to save in an XLSX worksheet ready.

But when I try to send the dataframe to this XLSX worksheet, the file is overwritten by removing all existing edits and sheets in the worksheet.

I'm trying to do so.

```
excel_name = 'data/nessus/My Scans/Janeiro_2019/teste.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_name,  engine='xlsxwriter')
df5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FullExport', index=False)
workbook=writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['FullExport']    
writer.save()
```

I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can not solve it.

PS:

This dataframe should be sent to the sheet called "FullExport" on line 2

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas

Comment: Run with out the 4th and 5th lines in your code. After writing to excel using `to_excel`, `writer.save()` would do

Answer (score 1):

In pandas version `0.24` they will be an option for `mode='a'`; however; right now you will have to:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_name, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = load_workbook(excel_name)
df5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FullExport', index=False)
writer.save()
write.close() # i think close() already runs the save function above
```