# Writing pandas dataframe to already formatted excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a template (formatted excel file) and I want to paste my dataframe to it in particular place. I try this:

```
template = pd.ExcelWriter('template.xls')
df.to_excel(template, startrow = 75, startcol = 3)
template.save()
```

It pasted df where I wanted, but my formatting is gone. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas)