# Add new row to existing excel file without overwriting the data (Python)

Tags: python, excel

So I copied this code from [How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas/47740262#47740262)

```
def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                   truncate_sheet=False, 
                   **to_excel_kwargs):
"""
Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
into [sheet_name] Sheet.
If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

Parameters:
  filename : File path or existing ExcelWriter
             (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
  df : dataframe to save to workbook
  sheet_name : Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
               (default: 'Sheet1')
  startrow : upper left cell row to dump data frame.
             Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
             in the existing DF and write to the next row...
  truncate_sheet : truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                   before writing DataFrame to Excel file
  to_excel_kwargs : arguments which will be passed to `DataFrame.to_excel()`
                    [can be dictionary]

Returns: None
"""
from openpyxl import load_workbook

import pandas as pd

# ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
    to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

# Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist 
try:
    FileNotFoundError
except NameError:
    FileNotFoundError = IOError


try:
    # try to open an existing workbook
    writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

    # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
    # if it was not specified explicitly
    if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
        startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

    # truncate sheet
    if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
        # index of [sheet_name] sheet
        idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
        # remove [sheet_name]
        writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
        # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
        writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

    # copy existing sheets
    writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
except FileNotFoundError:
    # file does not exist yet, we will create it
    pass

if startrow is None:
    startrow = 0

# write out the new sheet
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

# save the workbook
writer.save()
```

What the function does is: it adds a dataframe(row) to an existing excel file.
However this function is replacing the row of the original excel file, for the row of the dataframe.
How can I change/add to this function for it first to insert the row rather than repalce the row, thus maintaining the original data and adding the new one?

Answer (score 0):

After `# try to open an existing workbook
    writer.book = load_workbook(filename)`

Add `ws= writer.book[sheet_name]
ws.insert_rows("number of the row you want to insert")`