# how to calculate total against each month and create new excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

INPUT excel file:

```
PRODUCTPRICE    TIMEPLACED
2       14-JUN-18 02.53.33.347000 AM
3       14-JUN-18 03.05.15.210000 AM
4       14-JUN-18 02.26.11.959000 AM
30      14-JUL-18 02.53.33.347000 AM
20      14-JUL-18 03.05.15.210000 AM
20      14-MAR-19 02.53.33.347000 AM
10      14-MAR-18 03.05.15.210000 AM
30      14-MAR-18 02.26.11.959000 AM
```

output excel file.

```
TOTAL_PRODUCT_PRICE  DATE
9                   JUN-18
50                  JUL-18
60                  MAR-20



PRODUCTPRICE    TIMEPLACED
    2       14-JUN-18 02.53.33.347000 AM
    3       14-JUN-18 03.05.15.210000 AM
    4       14-JUN-18 02.26.11.959000 AM
    30      14-JUL-18 02.53.33.347000 AM
    20      14-JUL-18 03.05.15.210000 AM
    20      14-MAR-19 02.53.33.347000 AM
    10      14-MAR-18 03.05.15.210000 AM
    30      14-MAR-18 02.26.11.959000 AM
```

I will get input excel file like above now I want to write new excel by calculating total_product for each month and also want same details as in input excel below in new excel as well.what is the best method to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach:

Step 0: Try to get a better input format. Excel is not suitable for data processing.

**Step 1. Read the original excel:**
If step 0 fails, I would use `pandas`' `read_excel` function to get a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df_original = pd.read_excel('./your_input_excel.xlsx')
```

You likely will have to do date parsing. The `parse_dates` and `date_parser` parameters of `read_excel` could be of help. Documentation can be found over here: [read_excel docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

**Step 2. Store the original excel for later:**
After having parsed your dates in your `DataFrame`, make a [`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) of it:

```py
df_processing = df_original.copy()
```

**Step 3. Sum the prices that have the same month-year**:
With the `df_processing` DataFrame, you can sum all the values in the `PRODUCTPRICE` columns if they have the same month and year and assign the result to a `TOTAL_PRODUCT_PRICE` column. You can create a `DATE` column by only keeping the month and year information from `TIMEPLACED`.

Now you can drop the old `PRODUCTPRICE` and `TIMEPLACED` columns from `df_processing` and you have your output DataFrame.

**Step 4. Write the resulting DataFrame to an excel file:**
Write your output DataFrame to an excel file using the `to_excel` function:

```py
df_processing.to_excel("target_excel.xlsx")
```

[to_excel docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

**Step 5. Append the original DataFrame:**

Finally to append to the original excel, you can look into the following question:  [How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas?rq=1)