# Append a DataFrame [df] to existing sheet of existing Excel file - helper function is not working

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

A helper function(link below) is not working with the code below.  It gives error Sheet1 is existing.  Tested with Pandas 1.3.2, openpyxl 3.0.7.  I am not sute the function is able to append df to existing sheet, it seems ExcelWriter open a Sheet1 and not able to write to the sheet_name.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66599924/16857467

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    filename_out = 'excel_output.xlsx'
    list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    list_2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_1)
    append_df_to_excel(filename_out, df, header=None, index=False)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_2)
    append_df_to_excel(filename_out, df, header=None, index=False)
```

the error message in debug terminal is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user1\userspace\exceltest3.py", line 10, in <module>
    append_df_to_excel(filename_out, df, header=None, index=False)
  File "c:\Users\user1\userspace\exceltest2.py", line 102, in append_df_to_excel
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol, na_rep=na_rep, **to_excel_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2284, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "C:\Users\user1\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 840, in write
    writer.write_cells(
  File "C:\Users\user1\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 436, in write_cells       
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Sheet 'Sheet1' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.
```

and also this try gives same error.  writing to another sheet.  Workaround is to set if_sheet_exists='replace', since the book already has list_1 sheetname and we can not append to it but replace.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    filename_out = 'excel_output.xlsx'
    list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    list_2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_1)
    append_df_to_excel(filename_out, df, sheet_name='list1', header=None, index=False)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_2)
    append_df_to_excel(filename_out, df, sheet_name='list2', header=None, index=False)
```

from documentation of pandas.ExcelWriter, I understand it no longer allow appending df to same sheet.

any workaround or suggestion appreciated.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

```
if_sheet_exists{‘error’, ‘new’, ‘replace’}, default ‘error’
How to behave when trying to write to a sheet that already exists (append mode only).
error: raise a ValueError.
new: Create a new sheet, with a name determined by the engine.
replace: Delete the contents of the sheet before writing to it.
New in version 1.3.0.
```