# How to highlight unmatch row and update marking' in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, if-statement, merge

Everyone, I have some problems for to leaning program by myself

1. I have two different excel to compare...

Data1.xlsx

```
|  Name   |  Reg Date  |
|Annie    | 2021-07-01 |
|Billy    | 2021-07-02 |
|Cathrine | 2021-07-03 |
|David    | 2021-07-04 |
|Eric     | 2021-07-04 |
```

Data2.xlsx

```
|  Name   |   City    |  Reg Date  | Gender | Data1.xlsx |
|Alex     | Hong Kong | 2021-07-04 | Male   |            |
|Annie    | Hong Kong | 2021-07-01 | Female |            |
|Bob      | Taipei    | 2021-07-02 | Male   |            |
|Lucy     | Tokyo     | 2021-07-01 | Female |            |
|David    | London    | 2021-07-04 | Male   |            |
|Kate     | New York  | 2021-07-03 | Female |            |
|Cathrine | London    | 2021-07-03 | Female |            |
|Rose     | Hong Kong | 2021-07-04 | Female |            |
```

2. I get 'Name' & 'Reg Date' for key to merge

   ```
   import pandas as pd 
   dt1 = pd.read_excel('Data1.xlsx')
   dt2 = pd.read_excel('Data2.xlsx')
   df_merge = pd.merge(dt1.iloc[:, [0, 1]], dt2.iloc[:, [0, 2]], on=['Name', 'Reg Date'], how='outer', indicator=True)

   i = 0
   rows_to_color = []

   for a in df_merge.iloc[:, [2]].values:
       if a == 'both':
          rows_to_color.append(i)
       i += 1


   |  Name   |  Reg Date  |   _merge   |
   |Alex     | 2021-07-04 | right_only |
   |Annie    | 2021-07-01 | both       |
   |Billy    | 2021-07-02 | left_only  | 
   |Bob      | 2021-07-02 | right_only |
   |Lucy     | 2021-07-01 | right_only |
   |David    | 2021-07-04 | both       |
   |Eric     | 2021-07-04 | left_only  |
   |Kate     | 2021-07-03 | right_only |
   |Cathrine | 2021-07-03 | both       |
   |Rose     | 2021-07-04 | right_only |
   ```
3. I try to coding to highlight 'left_only' & 'right_only' for 'Data2.xlsx', but not work.

   ```
   def bg_color(col):
   color = '#ffffff'
   return 'background-color: %s' % color
   if i in rows_to_color:
       for i, x in col.iteritems():
           styled = df_merge.style.apply(bg_color)
   ```
4. I have no idea how to make highlight unmatch row and mark 'Y/N' in 'Data2.xlsx', below pic is my expected result. would you mind to teach me how to coding?

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwfN6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join in `merge` and set `Y/N` by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) first:

```
#change order dt2, dt1
df_merge = pd.merge(dt2, 
                    dt1[['Name', 'Reg Date']], 
                    on=['Name', 'Reg Date'], 
                    how='left', indicator=True)
df_merge['Data1.xlsx'] = np.where(df_merge.pop('_merge').eq('both'), 'Y', 'N')
print (df_merge)
       Name       City    Reg Date  Gender Data1.xlsx
0      Alex  Hong Kong  2021-07-04    Male          N
1     Annie  Hong Kong  2021-07-01  Female          Y
2       Bob     Taipei  2021-07-02    Male          N
3      Lucy      Tokyo  2021-07-01  Female          N
4     David     London  2021-07-04    Male          Y
5      Kate   New York  2021-07-03  Female          N
6  Cathrine     London  2021-07-03  Female          Y
7      Rose  Hong Kong  2021-07-04  Female          N
```

And then set colors by `N` rows:

```
def bg_color(x):
    c = 'background-color: yellow'
    # condition
    m = x["Data1.xlsx"].eq('N')
    # DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

    # set columns by condition
    return df1.mask(m, c)

styled = df_merge.style.apply(bg_color, axis=None)

styled.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and add to my knowledge, but i want to copy ' Data1.xlsx' column data of merged to original 'Data2' excel file, not save to new excel file...

Comment: @CHL - there are some another columns? Or some another sheets?

Comment: @CHL - Understand, what is reason cannot create another file? Or is possible use `styled.to_excel('Data2.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)` for overwrite file `Data2.xlsx` ?

Comment: Sorry English isn't my first language, I just have 'Data1' with 1 sheet and 'Data2' with 1 sheet excel files. Before compare two excel file, 'Data1.xlsx' column of 'Data2' is empty. I though can only copy and paste 'Y/N' value to 'column of Data2' excel file after compare. Maybe I have not enough programming logic...

Comment: @CHL - then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas) solution - possible, but not easy.

Comment: In addition to overwrite, is do you know any about 'copy and paste' method?

Comment: @CHL - it is python, not possible same way like human