# Pandas create a new sheet instead of adding the data in the active one

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am creating a spreadsheet with openpyxl and adding some data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import load_workbook

from collections import OrderedDict
workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active


def fill_static_values():
    sheet["A1"] = "Run No."
    sheet["A2"] = "MLIDMLPA"
    sheet["A48"] = "Patients here"
    
    sheet["B1"] = "Patient"

fill_static_values()

output = "./Name_of_run.xlsx"

workbook.save(filename=output)
```

Then my application do some data management and I want to add some of this data into the existing file.

```
book = load_workbook(output)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book

## ExcelWriter for some reason uses writer.sheets to access the sheet.
## If you leave it empty it will not know that sheet Main is already there
## and will create a new sheet.

writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

data_no_control.to_excel(writer, "sheet", startrow=2, startcol=3,
                        header=False,
                        index=False)

writer.save()
```

Solution found on this StackOverflow  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas/47740262#47740262)

However, this is creating and adding the data in the correct position but in a new sheet called sheet2. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The to_excel has incorrect sheet name. The `S` should be in CAPS. Change the line from
`data_no_control.to_excel(writer, "sheet", startrow=2, startcol=3,`
to
`data_no_control.to_excel(writer, "Sheet", startrow=2, startcol=3,`

As there is already a sheet in the excel, it is writing the data to Sheet2

**EDIT**
Noticed that you are using `writer.sheets`. If you want to use want the program pick up the first sheet from excel automatically, you can use this as well...

```
data_no_control.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=list(writer.sheets.keys())[0], startrow=2, startcol=3,
```

This will pick up the first sheet (in your case the only sheet) as the worksheet to update