# pandas dataframe to an existing excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i m trying to add a pandas data frame to create a new sheet in an existing excel workbook. it either deletes the workbook and just saves the data frame or it just does not work and it gives me weird errors. "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" i m not using zip files . here is my code :

```
import pandas
```

`   from openpyxl import load_workbook

```
book = load_workbook(target)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(target, engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

view.to_excel(writer, "FCST Aug 2022")
writer.save()
```

Comment: An Excel file is a zip file. Also, there are many questions here on SO dealing with this error.

Comment: none of them work

Comment: Dang, I had a sick solution to this but the question got closed while I was typing it

Comment: @smichael_44 - maybe you should post it in one of the linked threads, *assuming it hasn't been suggested already in them*. There are already many questions asking how to do this. No need to create yet more duplicates.

Comment: @BigBen it definitely was not posted when I was looking because I essentially had the same question a year ago, i'll take a look at some threads and see if there is anything new that I haven't seen, thank you

Comment: And of course you're free to leave a link here to the answer you post...

Comment: @vanetoj I posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73479475/18784484