# Insert a single cell of string above header row in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have my dataframe ready to be written to an excel file but I need to add a single cell of string above it. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the dataframe starting from the second row and then use other tools to write the first cell of your excel file.

Note that writing from pandas to excel overwrites its data, so we have to follow this order (but there are also methods [how to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20219254/14627505)).

**1.** Save the dataframe, specifying `startrow=1`:

```py
df.to_excel("filename.xlsx", startrow=1, index=False)
```

**2.** Write a cell value.

For example, using `openpyxl` (from a [GeeksforGeeks tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-value-in-excel-using-python/)):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# load excel file
workbook = load_workbook(filename="filename.xlsx")
 
# open workbook
sheet = workbook.active
 
# modify the desired cell
sheet["A1"] = "A60983A Register"
 
# save the file
workbook.save(filename="filename.xlsx")
```

Comment: I actually tried this but did it in the wrong sequence. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'label':['first','second','first','first','second','second'],
               'first_text':['how is your day','the weather is nice','i am feeling well','i go to school','this is good','that is new'],
               'second_text':['today is warm','this is cute','i am feeling sick','i go to work','math is hard','you are old'],
               'third_text':['i am a student','the weather is cold','she is cute','ii am at home','this is bad','this is trendy']})
```

```
df.loc[-1] = df.columns.values
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns=
    {"label": "Register", 'first_text':'', 'second_text':'', 'third_text':''}, 
    inplace=True)
```

Try this [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so you can change your data as well.