# Extract min, max and avg using pandas DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is my Dataframe printed with df.to_markdown())

| type | convesion time | covert json | data to convert | process completed | time taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INFO | 0 days 00:01:00 | 2023-03-09 18:56:57 | 23000 | 0 days 00:02:03 | 0 days 00:02:09 |
| INFO | 0 days 00:01:30 | 2023-03-09 19:00:01 | 30000 | 0 days 00:03:28 | 0 days 00:03:31 |
| INFO | 0 days 00:01:30 | 2023-03-09 19:00:01 | 50000 | 0 days 00:03:28 | 0 days 00:06:31 |
| INFO | 0 days 00:00:30 | 2023-03-09 19:00:01 | 1000 | 0 days 00:00:28 | 0 days 00:00:31 |

I want to get

- Min data to convert its respective conversion time, process
  completed time and total time(conversion time +process
  completed),time taken
- Max data to convert its respective conversion time, process completed
  time and total time(conversion
  time +process completed),time taken
- Avg data to convert its respective conversion time, process completed
  time and total time(conversion
  time +process
  completed),time taken

i tried,

```
df.loc[df['data to convert']==data_min, 'convesion time']
df['time taken'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time taken'])
df['time taken'].sum()
```

Am not able to get what am expecting.

Expected Output:

| d | Data to convert | Conversion time | Process completed | total time(process+conversion) | Time taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MIN | 1000 | 00:00:30 | 00:00:28 | 00:00:58 | 00:00:31 |
| MAX | 50000 | 00:01:30 | 00:03:28 | 00:04:58 | 00:06:31 |
| AVG | 25500 | 00:01:00 | 00:01:58 | 00:02:58 | 00:03:31 |

Comment: `Am not able to get what am expecting.` - What is expecting from sample data?

Comment: i will add expected output give me a minute

Comment: OK, if change `data to convert` value `23000` to `23000000` what is `time taken` in ouput for max?

Comment: it depends on processing i can take 10 minutes or 1 hour... based on GPU, CPU

Comment: I think from sample data `0 days 00:02:09` or `0 days 00:06:31` ?

Comment: I will be higher one only... but this data i won'r calculate. it comes from server

Comment: Unfortunately not undertand each other. From sample data not clear, how is count `MAX` and `MN` ouput rows. MAX is count from row if `data to convert` is max? Or MAX is count from maximal of each column?

Comment: MIN, MAX and Average will be based on "data to convert"

Comment: OK, so need first my solution.

Comment: suppose  data to convert value has 100, 2300, 23000 and 23000000  --> here min is 100 and will get time conversion, process time for  the row 100 and max will be 23000000 and its respective time process, conversion time e.t.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#create default index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#convert columns to timedeltas
cols = ['convesion time','process completed','time taken']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_timedelta)

#create new column
df['total time'] = df['convesion time'].add(df['process completed'])

#convert values to numeric
df['data to convert'] = df['data to convert'].astype(int)

#get rows with maximal and minimal values
df1 = (df.loc[df['data to convert'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax']), 
              ['data to convert'] + cols + ['total time']]
        )
df1.index = ['MIN','MAX']

#add mean row
df1.loc['AVG'] = df1.mean()
print (df1)
     data to convert  convesion time process completed      time taken  \
MIN           1000.0 0 days 00:00:30   0 days 00:00:28 0 days 00:00:31   
MAX          50000.0 0 days 00:01:30   0 days 00:03:28 0 days 00:06:31   
AVG          25500.0 0 days 00:01:00   0 days 00:01:58 0 days 00:03:31   

         total time  
MIN 0 days 00:00:58  
MAX 0 days 00:04:58  
AVG 0 days 00:02:58
```

---

```
df2 = df1.unstack().to_frame().T
print (df2)
  data to convert                    convesion time                  \
              MIN      MAX      AVG             MIN             MAX   
0          1000.0  50000.0  26000.0 0 days 00:00:30 0 days 00:01:30   

                         process completed                  \
                     AVG               MIN             MAX   
0 0 days 00:01:07.500000   0 days 00:00:28 0 days 00:03:28   

                              time taken                  \
                     AVG             MIN             MAX   
0 0 days 00:02:21.750000 0 days 00:00:31 0 days 00:06:31   

                              total time                  \
                     AVG             MIN             MAX   
0 0 days 00:03:10.500000 0 days 00:00:58 0 days 00:04:58   

                          
                     AVG  
0 0 days 00:03:29.250000
```

EDIT: If need all maximals and all minimal rows:

```
#create default index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#convert columns to timedeltas
cols = ['convesion time','process completed','time taken']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_timedelta)

#create new column
df['total time'] = df['convesion time'].add(df['process completed'])

#convert values to numeric
df['data to convert'] = df['data to convert'].astype(int)

#get rows with maximal and minimal values
df1 = df[df['data to convert'].eq(df['data to convert'].max())]
df1.index = ['MAX'] * len(df1)

df2 = df[df['data to convert'].eq(df['data to convert'].min())]
df2.index = ['MIN'] * len(df2)
print (df2)

out = pd.concat([df1, df2])

#add mean row
out.loc['AVG'] = out.mean()
print (out)
```

Comment: Thanks, Can i write this into excel where input DF in one sheet and output DF into another sheet in same excel?

Comment: @ditil- Sure, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas)

Comment: df1 = (df.loc[df['data to convert'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax']), 
  File "/apps/tools/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3974, in aggregate
    result, how = aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/apps/tools/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/aggregation.py", line 586, in aggregate
    return agg_list_like(obj, arg, _axis=_axis), None
  File "/apps/tools/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/aggregation.py", line 672, in agg_list_like
    raise ValueError("no results")
ValueError: no results

Comment: am getting error @jezrael

Comment: @ditil - What is `print (df['data to convert'].dtype)` ?

Comment: Its printing -- > object

Comment: @ditil - It means there are non numeric data. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas)

Comment: I did this
`df['data to convert'] = df['data to convert'].astype(int)

df1 = (df.loc[df['data to convert'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax']), 
              ['data to convert'] + cols + ['total time']]
        .set_axis(['MIN','MAX']))`


am getting error  -->

f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: @ditil - Can you change `.set_axis(['MIN','MAX']))` to `.set_axis(['MIN','MAX'], inplace=False, axis=0))` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252437/discussion-between-ditil-and-jezrael).