# Pandas deletes all other sheets when using df.to_excel()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with 6 sheets, in one of sheets I would like to a append data some data but keep the other sheets intact.

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('myfile.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'log')
d = {'Date': [2023], 'Time': [180855],'Q': ['2']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_final = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_final.to_excel(xls, sheet_name='log')
```

So I specify the sheet and only interact with the sheet `log` , however my new saved sheet only has the `log` sheet saved and all other sheets deleted.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas)

Comment: @BigBen Im trying to get it to work but it dosen't seem to work in my case. when I run it, it deletes my notebook content and then crashes. I've tried tinkering with it, but no luck :/

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems that the answer is pretty easy actually

Instead of

```
df_final.to_excel(xls, sheet_name='log')
```

I needed

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx', mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="log")
```

So final code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('myfile.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'log')
d = {'Date': [2023], 'Time': [180855],'Q': ['2']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_final = pd.concat([df1,df2])
with pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx', mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="log")
```