# Best way to dump large pandas dataframe into an *existing* Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a large `pandas` dataframe that I'd like to dump into an existing excel file (essentially, that file then takes the data and does Excel-y things with it, and I want to update a single `raw_data` tab).

For now I use code from here: [How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas) that looks like

```
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('the_file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer: 
     data_filtered.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="raw_data")
```

But the dump is now so memory- and processor- intensive that it takes down my computer for ten minutes at a stretch.

I see solutions for dumping to a new excel file, but nothing good for overwriting an tab of an existing file.

What is the best, most efficient way to do this?  I am also game for writing to a new tempfile, and then copying that tempfile into the existing file's `raw_data` tab - but the process needs to end with the existing file being updated.

Many thanks!
/YGA

Comment: Did you try `xlwings` instead of `openpyxl`?

Comment: For both warcupine and mashkati - Can you give me example code?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

`pd.ExcelWriter` has a parameter `if_sheet_exists`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(filestr, engine='openpyxl',mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw_Data')
```

This will clear the contents and formatting of the sheet and replace it with your dataframe.

You will need at least version 1.3.0 of Pandas.

Comment: Unfortunately - that is still very slow.  Essentially - I need to find a way to do this without using openpyxl, and on a mac so xlwings is not an option.